# Download and install the amd64-genome-desktop iso

Tags: linux, debian

I wonder if I download the `debian-live-8.0.0-amd64-gnome-desktop.iso` from the page  [enter link description here](http://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/8.0.0-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/) and use it for the installation? How that would be diffrent then the `debian-8.10.0-amd64-netinst.iso`?

Comment: No difference, except that with the `netinst` you have choices of Desktops etc.

Answer (score 1):

The "netinst" uses the internet for installation packages, they are not in the ISO so they have to download.  I think you have more choices this way and the ISO is smaller.

The Gnome ISO has all packages in the ISO that are required for a full Gnome install without downloading any packages.  It still might download packages to update outdated packages.

In the end, if you do not have internet on the computer to be installed on, the Gnome ISO would give you a full featured install and the netinst would not.